# Make an external hard drive unbootable and recover old data

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I stored important data such as pictures, software, and backup of my websites in an external hard drive (2TB). When downloading and running Windows 11 setup I mistakenly made this drive bootable.

Is there a way to make this device unbootable and recover my precious data? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you mean that while installing Windows you have formatted the drive? What was the format with which this drive was previously formatted (NTFS etc)?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I haven't formatted the disk drive. I use to upload screenshots on my website for different steps. I was trying to take screenshots for installing process of Windows 11 using media creation tool.  In this process, when 'Windows 11 Setup' asked to "Choose which media to use" I selected 'USB Flash drive'. Then the setup automatically recognized the external hard drive and converted it into bootable. I was waiting for a warning or format disk dialog. I got puzzled when I see that the drive was converted into bootable media. Currently, the File system is FAT32.

Comment: Please see in Please see in - https://prnt.sc/UT5L_yKND-vT

Comment: Kindly, respond harrymc.

Comment: Does this mean that the data is still there and all you want is to make it not bootable?

Comment: Yes. absolutely.

Comment: I have not done anything with the hard drive since the occurrence.

Comment: At best partial file system recovery, best part of the recovery probably raw (no filenames/folder structures. Making it non bootable has nothing to do with this. You need file recovery software.

Comment: Making a disk bootable should not cause data to become unreadable.  It sounds like there may have been more to this then making the disk bootable.  Yoy may be able to reciver data with testdisk or photorec

Answer (score 0):

Windows Media Creation tool overwrote the start of the drive (little less than 8 GB), in case of NTFS this typically means:

- MFT is overwritten (if MFT non fragmented)
- Or portion of MFT overwritten (if MFT was fragmented)

[image]

You should not change anything on the drive!

Assume non file system based recovery is often the maximum best result, this means files can be recover though using a raw or signature scan, without original filenames or folder structure. Only IF the MFT was fragmented partial file system reconstruction is (may be) possible.

Of course files that were actually stored towards the start of the drive, within the approximately 8 GB of overwritten data can *not* be recovered. Also, without file system reconstruction only *contiguous* files can be recovered intact.

To determine if (partial) file system reconstruction is possible I suggest you start with a tool that is capable of virtual file system reconstruction. Examples are:

- DMDE (dmde.com)
- R-Studio (r-tt.com)
- GetDataBack (runtime.org)

DMDE and R-Studio attempt file system reconstruction but also scan for files based on file signatures. Good results were also achieved using GetDataBack (set scan depth to ****). DMDE is a tad more complex to use but allows for greater configurability and in hands of a person with more than average file system knowledge will probably yield best result.

If you decide filenames are of no importance, the free PhotoRec (cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) may be all you need.